# Detect SIGUSR1 in C code and print Hello World

Tags: python, c, pipe, signals

I have a relatively trivial problem, with working reproducible code (you can run it direct from your environment

Essentially

I have some C and Python code.

My  python code

Creates two pipes tomcat_1 and tomcat_2, these pipes can read and write respectively.

Now using my tomcat_2 pipe I write the string F-14 TOMCAT, in my C code, I open the two pipes and read from tomcat_2 pipe the contents of what has been written

This stuff works without any dramas.

```
    import os
import signal


#Remove existing fifos if not cleaned up from last time.
try:
    os.unlink('/tmp/tomcat_1')
    os.unlink('/tmp/tomcat_2')
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda x,y: None) #Setup signal handler with no-op lambda expression


os.mkfifo('/tmp/tomcat_1') #Fifos can be constructed in python
os.mkfifo('/tmp/tomcat_2')



r = open('/tmp/tomcat_1','r')
w = open('/tmp/tomcat_2','w')

w.write("F-14 TOMCAT")
w.flush()
w.close()
with open('/tmp/tomcat_2', 'r') as f:
    pid = int(f.read())

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
while True:
    data = r.read()
    if len(data) > 0:
        print('PYTHON: Received ' + data) # FIFOs can be read from like any other file

# Close reading pipe
r.close()



signal.pause() #mimics pause(2)

print('PYTHON: ending process')

r.close()

#cleanup fifos
os.unlink('/tmp/tomcat_1')
os.unlink('/tmp/tomcat_2')
```

Now

I have C code that can read the data written to the pipe here it is

```
 void signal_handler(int SIG);

volatile sig_atomic_t g_sigint_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t g_sigusr1_flag = 0;
int fd1;
int fd2;

void exchange_signal_handler(int signo);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    char trader[100];

    fd2 = open("/tmp/tomcat_1",O_WRONLY);
    fd1 = open("/tmp/tomcat_2", O_RDONLY);

    if (fd1== -1) {
        perror("open pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fd2== -1) {
        perror("open pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (signal(SIGINT, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        printf("Unable to register signal handler for SIGINT\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (signal(SIGUSR1, exchange_signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        printf("Unable to register exchange signal handler for SIGUSR1\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[1024];
    int buf_size = read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
    buf[buf_size] ='\0';
    printf("Received data: %s\n", buf);

    while (!g_sigint_flag) {
        if (g_sigusr1_flag) {
            g_sigusr1_flag = 0; // Reset the flag
        }
    }

    close(fd2);
    close(fd1);
    return 0;
}

void signal_handler(int SIG) {
    if (SIG == SIGINT) {
        printf("Terminated\n");
        g_sigint_flag = 1;
    }
}

void exchange_signal_handler(int signo) {
    if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
        printf("Received SIGUSR1 signal from exchange\n");
        g_sigusr1_flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Now my issue is, when my python code  sends a SIGUSR1 signal to tomcat_2 pipe, in Python , my C Code should detect this and print a hello world

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Why this  line of code: `char trader[100];`?

Answer (score 0):

Code has at least this problem.  Unknown if this is the source of OP's issues.

**Risk: writing outside buffer**

Code writes outside buffer when `1024` bytes read.

```
char buf[1024];
// int buf_size = read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
int buf_size = read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
buf[buf_size] ='\0';
printf("Received data: %s\n", buf);
```

or

```
char buf[1024];
int buf_size = read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
// printf("Received data: %s\n", buf);
printf("Received data: %.*s\n", buf_size, buf);
```